# paypal integration with phonegap

Tags: cordova, paypal, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am building my app in *phonegap* build method. Now I am trying to integrate Paypal and *phonegap*. I have found a plugin for this, and trying this with [GitHub](https://github.com/romk1n/MyCordovaShop) .

I have replaced `YOUR_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID` in *index.js* with my client id which has created with my sandbox merchent account and kept `YOUR_PRODUCTION_CLIENT_ID` as it is for testing.
After building the app it came nicely and I colud make the payment by entering the sandbox username and password. I got the response as status approved, but the payment doesnt shows in paypal section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long testing also i couldn't do with the paypal SDK plugi. At last i did with the normal methode of integration. The entire operation has done in a new tab, and once the process is over the bsck button press cleses this tab.
Anyway thanks a lot A-Droid Tech

Comment: Helllo I am facing the same issue, it shows payment success but when I check the account nothing has happened. Can you please elaborate how you got this working. @Albert

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:- First install running this command cordova plugin add com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk

Step2:-

Download   https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin

Copy paypal-mobile-js-helper and cdv-plugin-paypal-mobile-sdk js files from www folder and paste into your project js folder.

Step3:-

Add reference of these files into your index.js file

Step4:-

Add payPalService.js file into your project from

https://gist.github.com/mssdineshsambial/f679ab69597c49b25f25

Step 5:-

Add lines into APP.js file

.constant(‘shopSettings’,{

payPalSandboxId :’Aar8HZzvc5NztVWodTBpOiOod9wWrBDrJUjyvRr4WsxcCD28xYig7oecfYsqxQUDu5QHptPpSALirxZD’,

payPalProductionId : ‘production id here’,

payPalEnv: ‘PayPalEnvironmentSandbox’, // for testing production for production

payPalShopName : ‘MyShopName’,

payPalMerchantPrivacyPolicyURL : ‘url to policy’,

payPalMerchantUserAgreementURL : ‘ url to user agreement ‘

})

Replace PayPalSandboxId and payPal Production Id with your send box Id and production client id

Step 6:-

Add these lines under your controller button click to start paypal payment.

PaypalService.initPaymentUI().then(function () {

PaypalService.makePayment(90, “Total Amount”).then(function (response) {

alert(“success”+JSON.stringify(response));

}, function (error) {

alert(“Transaction Canceled”);

});

});

Comment: thanks A-Droid Tech for the reply. I am not familiar with ionic. I used to do build apps with mobile jquery and angular js. Can you please suggest methode for that? Please note that i am using phonegap build methode.

Comment: I will update my answer,Ionic and Phonegap both use the same plugins (Cordova Plugins) so, you can simply use in phonegap also

Comment: yes, install  cordova plugin add com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk, it will also worrk in phonegap.For referance you can review it : https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin

Comment: yes i followed the same. let me tell the steps i followed i have added <gap:plugin name="com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk" version="3.1.8" /> in config.xml then in index.html i have added  <button id="buyNowBtn"> Buy Now !</button>. as they explained i changed index .js file with they have given. in that js i canged    "PayPalEnvironmentProduction": "YOUR_PRODUCTION_CLIENT_ID",
       "PayPalEnvironmentSandbox": "YOUR_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID"     to       "PayPalEnvironmentProduction": "YOUR_PRODUCTION_CLIENT_ID",
       "PayPalEnvironmentSandbox": "BHHjhdjuiewiu7878233rgdsajhbDiujhdshdsfh".

Comment: somebody know why does amount is reinit to $1 if it is a big amount (like $1900) ? thanks